# Set timer for specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a grid with 25 clickable items. If someone clicks on a desired item, a timer for this item should start. After the timer reaches 0, the item should get hidden. What is the best way to do this?

This is the grid:

```
<ul class="field">
        <?php
            for($i = 1; $i<26; $i++){
        ?>
            <li id="item-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-specie="test-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-level="0" class="field-item">
                <img>    
            <!--</li>--> 
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

And this is the jquery part:

```
$(".field-item").click(function()
{
    var level = $(this).data('level');
    level ++;
    $(this).data('level',level);
    $(this).find( "img" ).attr("src","../css/images/plant-1-"+level+".png");

    setTimeout(progress, 3000);
});
```

And this is the function that should only hide the grid-item that has been clicked on. (I know this won't work by the way, I just don't know how to do this part.)

```
function progress(){
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(progress.bind(this), 3000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should only hide the grid-item that has been clicked on

You could pass the current instance of clicked element using **[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)** as mentioned in **[*@Andreas comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147249/set-timer-for-specific-elements/38147517#comment-63724169)**, so it will be :

```
setTimeout(progress.bind(this), 3000);
```

Instead of :

```
setTimeout(progress, 3000);
```

Hope this helps.